# Wordpress outputting multiple body css styles in dynamic css style tag in header

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am having a very strange issue: WordPress is outputting multiple body classes and style sets into the style section in the header. Here's what it looks like:

```
<style type="text/css" title="dynamic-css" class="options-output">body{font-family:Poppins;line-height:18px;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;color:#ffffff;font-size:16px;}body{font-family:Poppins;line-height:16px;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;color:#ffffff;font-size:14px;}body{font-family:Poppins;line-height:20px;font-weight:700;font-style:normal;color:#ffffff;font-size:14px;}</style>
```

And the website is:

http://www.arctictulsa.com.php56-4.dfw3-2.websitetestlink.com/

Has anyone had any experience with this issue? I feel like it's happening, because of multiple plugins, but it's always possible to be the theme. The problem is that it's impossible to set basic styles for the body because it's setting the body font style to white and bold and if I override that in the theme CSS, I have to raise the specificity which screws up other styles.

Comment: Where does the issue come from? I have no idea. What's a quick fix? `!important`. Should you use `!important`? No! What should you do? Try **changing the theme** and **disabling plugins** until you find the culprit.

Comment: disabling plugins one by one and check.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what was causing the issue. Redux was generating a new body class for each separate section style in the theme. Disabling all of the custom css in these modules fixed the issue.